# MessageUI framework issue for UITextField contents are not displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, messageui

I've included messageUI framework in my app for sending mail.It contains five UITextField where the values entered by user should be displayed in mail body. Here is my code

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailer setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Appointment From Mr/Mrs. %@",text1.text]];

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"info@xxx.com", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];



    NSString *emailBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name :%@\nDate: %@\nPreferred Time Slot: %@\nE-Mail:%@\nSpecific Requests:",text1.text,text2.text,text3.text,text4.text,text5.text]; 

    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];


    [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];

    [mailer release];
}
```

The issue i'm facing is that all the four text field values are displayed only the fifth text field values are not displayed..Any idea?...am i missing anything?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the following line of code

```
 NSString *emailBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name :%@\nDate: %@\nPreferred Time Slot: %@\nE-Mail:%@\nSpecific Requests:%@",text1.text,text2.text,text3.text,text4.text,text5.text];
```

you will get your requirements...Dont forget to use resignFirstresponder to hide keyboard after u entered text...

Comment: Thanks for the answer and additional info..i thought of asking that in some other question...

Answer (score 2):

You only have four `%@` in the form at string, thus the last parameter supplied to the format method is ignored.

Change the format string to have five parameters:

```
NSString *emailBody =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name :%@\nDate: %@\nPreferred Time Slot: %@\nE-Mail:%@\nSpecific Requests:%2",text1.text,text2.text,text3.text,text4.text,text5.text];
```